# Limit console output while maintaining output to file? C++

Tags: c++, file-io, console, output, primes

Language: C++

My assignment is to write a program that allows a user to enter a number between 30 and 2000 and list the prime numbers up to that number. For example, a user enters the number 50.. the program will then find every prime number between 3 and 50 and display it to the console. The code I have written does just that.

The second set of instructions say to limit the console output to only 10 prime numbers (no matter what the user input is), but write all the prime numbers to a file.

Using the same example as before.. these are the prime numbers between 3 and 50:
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47

The console needs to show only 10 of those numbers while the rest are written to a file. Is it possible for me to only display 10 integers on my console while writing ALL (no matter how many) to a file?

Thank you in advance for reading, if you need more info to answer the question, please message me.

bool isPrime;

```
   for(int n = 2; n < integer; n++) {

      isPrime = isPrimeNumber(n);

      if(isPrime == true)
          cout<<n<<" ";
   }
   return 0;
}

int isPrimeNumber(int n) {
   bool isPrime = true;

   for(int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++) {
      if (n%i == 0) {
         isPrime = false;
         break;
      }
   }
   return isPrime;
```

Comment: *"Is it possible for me to only display 10 integers on my console while writing ALL (no matter how many) to a file?"* Yes, it is possible to do so.

Comment: Divide-and-conquer is awesome. 1) Can you adapt your *initial* program to write to a file instead of the console? 2) Can you adapt your *initial* program to write only 10 primes (to the console) instead of all of them? If you cannot do both of these, work on them first. Once you can do both of these, you problem morphs into merging your two programs. *(So there are three main steps. Please pick one of these for your question.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a counter variable which keeps track of how many times you have called cout.

```
//open file
int counter = 0;    

for(int n = 2; n < integer; n++){ 
    isPrime = isPrimeNumber(n); 

    if(isPrime == true){
        if(counter < 10){
            cout<<n<<" ";
            counter++;
        }
        //Write to file
    }
}
//Close file
```

Extra points:

isPrimeNumber returns a bool so your function should look like:

```
bool isPrimeNumber(int n)
```

You can then get rid of your 'isPrime' variable in the for loop and just say:

```
if(isPrimeNumber(n))
```

If statements implicitly check if a value is true if you do not specify a comparison.

You can also slightly optimise your isPrimeNumber function by changing it to the following (again eliminating the need for the isPrime variable):

```
bool isPrimeNumber(int n){

    for(int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++){ 
        if (n%i == 0) return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```